# What's wrong with my robots.txt file to block Google?

Tags: robots.txt

I have a website and I don't want this website to be visible on Google. So I deployed a robots.txt file. But the homepage of the website is still visible on Google. Here is the full code of my robots.txt copy-pasted below-

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /private/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /_/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /index.html
Disallow: /images
Disallow: /about.html
```

Comment: "... still visible on Google." - Just to add, if the homepage is already indexed, then `robots.txt` is not a particularly quick way of removing it.

Comment: Robots.txt provides instructions for spiders, but there are other ways that Google can find your site. Use noindex to specifically tell Google not to index it.

Comment: @w3dk Your are right - not fast at all, however, I do not think there is a faster way. If the robots.txt file is read, it can be 24-48 hours until removal. Google does not have to fetch the page to enforce this, it is a simple query type of operation against any URL that fits the relatively simple regex(ish) pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to allowed to crawl your website on Google search result, then use this robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

These will block all directories.

But if many website links to your website, then Google will start displaying this snippet in future.

[image]

Now if you don't want to index that website competely, [then use noindex meta-tags/HTTP headers](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag). That meta tags simply no index your all pages, but it is allowed to crawl. So if your main concern is about to, not visible in search result, then I highly recommended to use noindex tags.

But don't use it both, because when the site is [blocked by robots.txt then Google will not going to see your meta-tags/http headers.](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag#combining-crawling-with-indexing--serving-directives)

Answer (score 0):

Use Disallow: / to block your entire domain from being crawled by google bots.